# can someone suggest dbms systems for node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Can you please suggest good database which can be accessed using node.js? Basically, I am using node webkit and i want good dbms at the backend. so pls provide me some plugins if any with external dependencies?

Comment: How come this got upvoted? It's clearly off-topic...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should go with sqlite3.

The sqlite3 module also works with node-webkit if node-webkit contains a supported version of Node.js engine.

get it from the below linkhttps://www.npmjs.org/package/sqlite3

Comment: Please don't encourage these types of questions.